# Issue regarding iostream in android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, iostream

```
While trying to execute a program based on C++ in android via NDK platform, the compilation is giving error that 'iostream' and 'vector' header files are not found, as I have included both of them in my C++ code.
M using android-ndk-r5b and compiling it with Cygwin.
I have seen most of the header files (even iostream & vector) in the folder **root\android-ndk-r5b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\include\** but dont know why its still showing the error.
I have to fetch some header files(*.h) and some cpp files also for my program, also guide me where to place the header files & how to mention them in make file.
My android make file is:

**ANDROID.MK**

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := NDK1
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp) 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%) 
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_STL := stlport_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I have searched but still dont found the command how to specify the header files in this android.mk !
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`APP_STL` directive need to go into `Application.mk` file.

Please read the documentation more carefully (in docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html file):

> You can however select a different implementation by setting the variable APP_STL to something else in your Application.mk, for example:
>
> APP_STL := stlport_static