# How to convert int to String(?) in JNI?

Tags: java, android, c++, string, java-native-interface

I had got a ***int[ ]*** array, and I want to convert each element of it into ***String***(?) in ***JNI***, and finally concatenate them as a ***String***(?) (include the comma).

For example:

```
// java code
int testIntArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
String arrayString = "";

jni.constructArrayString(testIntArray, arrayString);

// the print content should like this: 1,2,3
System.out.println("ArrayString: " + arrayString);
```

---

```
// jni code
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL constructArrayString (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jintArray jArr, jstring jstr) {
    // to do sth.
    // code maybe like the follow

    jint *arr = env -> GetIntArrayElements(jArr, 0);
    int len = env -> GetArrayLength(jArr);
    char *c_str = env -> GetStringUTFChars(jstr, 0);

    if(c_str == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        // how to concatenate the arr[i], arr[i+1] and the comma ','
        // and finally make the arrayString like the string: 1,2,3 ?
    }
}
```

I know that, there's no a direct way which just can convert the ***int-type*** into ***string-type*** data or something else but should be operable in ***JNI***, and concatenate them as a ***String*** at last!

If it is hard to do with the ***void*** return-type, just change it! Thanx, in advance!

===========================================================================
New problem:

First, thanks @Jorn Vernee answer so much, it's seems the good way I should take. However, when I'm trying this way, there's comes an intractable problem about the ***std::stringstream***. Well, even instantiating it will crash the application. And, sadly I'm new to ***JNI***, have no experience in debugging a crash problem with JVM runtime error. And I had checked @Moe Bataineh [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709501/c-jni-crashes-hangs-when-doing-any-io-streams) which really seems like me, however it's applying on Windows with ***MiniGW*** or ***Cygwin*** something I don't know, so it's hlepless for me.

Code in JNI like this:

```
#include "utils_JniInterface.h"
#include <android/log.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#define TAG "JNI-Log"
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_utils_JniInterface_constructRGBArrayString (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jintArray jArr){
    jint *arr = env -> GetIntArrayElements(jArr, 0);
    int len = env -> GetArrayLength(jArr);

    std::stringstream result;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        result << arr[i];

        if(i < len - 1) {
            result << ',';
        }
    }

    env -> ReleaseIntArrayElements(jArr, arr, 0);

    return env -> NewStringUTF(result.str().data());
}

// int[] a = {1,2,3} ⇒ String b = "1,2,3"
```

Any good ideas or suggestions about this problem?

Comment: You mean a Java String? Do you want to pass it back to Java too?

Comment: @ Jorn Vernee No, I don't mean to convert the ***int*** into ***string*** in ***JNI***. I just want to make each element of the ***int[ ]*** array can be operable and concatenate them. If there's no necessary, it's would be better never pass it back to Java, just use the pointer！

Comment: Have you looked at [JNI Functions?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html). There's a method called `GetIntArrayElements` that just returns a `jint*` which you can treat as an `int[]` if you wanted.

Comment: You can't set the `arrayString`, Strings are immutable. You'd have to create a new one.

Comment: @ Jorn Vernee Well, it's welcome to create it in ***JNI***, and return it back to ***Java***.

Comment: @JornVernee *You can't set the `arrayString`.* Oh, yes you **can** if you're using JNI.  :-)  You just shouldn't as it's a great way to break things.  You can also change the value of immutable `Integer` objects.  That's *also* a great way to break things.

Comment: @frankjorsn If you're passing a `String` object from Java to JNI, you wouldn't be *creating* it in native code, you'd be updating it.  While you *can* do that in native code, you really shouldn't because the JVM considers `String` objects to be immutable.  If you change the value of a `String` object in native code you can cause major hard-to-identify and impossible-to-fix problems with your Java code.  In the code you have posted, every single `String` object that's holding an empty `""` value would likely get changed to the data you add to the object you passed to your native code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Sure, there's always a way to get around it. Even in Java you could simply modify the backing `char[]` through reflection. But let's not stray from the light of API too far.

Comment: @JornVernee I only brought it up because that seemed to be the direction where this was headed...

Comment: @ Andrew Henle Hello, have you ever take a look of Jorn Vernee's answer? Now, I'm suffering of the ***std::stringstream***, do you have any suggestions about this?

Comment: Is this some sort of JNI exercise? If not, why not do in Java?

Comment: @Tom Blodget Well, it's not a JNI exercise. Cause I need to resolve a big string-array (about pixels info), so I think it's better to break it in JNI to improve the efficiency of my program.

Answer (score 1):

This pretty straight forward:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Main_callCPP(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jintArray ints) {
    jint* jints = env->GetIntArrayElements(ints, 0);
    int length = env->GetArrayLength(ints);

    std::stringstream result;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result << jints[i];
        if(i < length - 1) {
            result << ',';
        }
    }

    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(ints, jints, JNI_ABORT);

    return env->NewStringUTF(result.str().data());
}
```

Where the Java signature would be:

```
private static native String callCPP(int[] ints);
```

(off course the name can be anything you want). And usage:

```
int[] ints = { 1, 2, 3 };
String result = callCPP(ints);
System.out.println(result); // prints '1,2,3'
```

Comment: Well, strangely, my demo-app crashed when I apply ***std::stringstream*** method. What's going on? Is there something should be notice when use ***using namespace std***? Or is there're some settings should be configured?

Comment: @frankjorsn Make sure you're using these exact function signatures. The JVM does not check that they coincide between Java and C/C++ at runtime.

Comment: @ Jorn Vemee I'm totally confused now. Here is a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709501/c-jni-crashes-hangs-when-doing-any-io-streams. Could you be more specific to have an explanation on this problem?

Comment: @frankjorsn I have never seen that problem before. I'm using MinGW myself which seems to solve the problem (as someone mentions in the comments.)

Answer (score 0):

helpful link: [Issue regarding iostream in android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781766/issue-regarding-iostream-in-android-ndk?rq=1)

When utilizing **std::stringstream** ,I also got the following error;

> fatal error: 'sstream' file not found

```
#include <sstream>
```

> ^ 1 error generated.

Solution that helped me was creating a file called "**Application.mk**" (Note: case-sensitive). The only line you need to add is:

> APP_STL := stlport_static

Put the "**Application.mk**" file in your "jni" folder this is same location your "Android.mk" file is. This worked for me in eclipse, and I can assume it works for android studio too.

Here's a link with alternatives: [Android ndk-build iostream: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130429/android-ndk-build-iostream-no-such-file-or-directory?rq=1)

Hope this helps @frank jorsn